# My Kafka broker cluster on vm has can not recieve record from kafka-console-producer

Tags: apache-kafka

I have encountered problem that my console producer can't access kafka-broker on vm(azure).
what's the problem?

This is My VM configuration

[image: VM configuration]

This is My error message from kafka console

```
    [2020-07-14 14:51:17,377] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error connecting to node data3.kafka.com:6667 (id: 1004 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
    java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: data3.kafka.com:6667
            at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doConnect(Selector.java:235)
            at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:214)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:864)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.access$700(NetworkClient.java:64)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:1035)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:920)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:508)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Unknown Source)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doConnect(Selector.java:233)
            ... 9 more
    [2020-07-14 14:51:17,691] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error connecting to node data2.kafka.com:6667 (id: 1003 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
    java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: data2.kafka.com:6667
            at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doConnect(Selector.java:235)
            at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:214)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:864)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.access$700(NetworkClient.java:64)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:1035)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:920)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:508)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Unknown Source)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doConnect(Selector.java:233)
            ... 9 more
    [2020-07-14 14:51:17,844] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error connecting to node data1.kafka.com:6667 (id: 1002 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
    java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: data1.kafka.com:6667
            at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doConnect(Selector.java:235)
            at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:214)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:864)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.access$700(NetworkClient.java:64)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:1035)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:920)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:508)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: command : kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list 2xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6667 --topic test --producer.config ../../config/producer.VM.properties

Comment: ../../config/producer.VM.properties 

bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://2xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6667,PLAINTEXT://22xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6668,PLAINTEXT://22xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6669

# specify the compression codec for all data generated: none, gzip, snappy, lz4
compression.type=none

Answer (score 0):

I was just added 3 rows in my hosts file which were

22.33.44.55 `data1.kafka.com`
22.33.44.55 `data2.kafka.com`
22.33.44.55 `data3.kafka.com`

It just works.